# How remove "bottom overflowed by infinity pixels" error when 2 Column are imbricated?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm new in Flutter,
I would like to create this
[image]

So I created two widget, one with column 1 and its child with column 2.

The problem is that I got this error "bottom overflowed by infinity pixels", despite the height and width defined.

Could you help me please ?

The parent widget:

```java
class LogingPage extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        width: size.width,
        height: size.height,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            brandDisplayContent(),
            //buttonsDisplayContent(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The child widget:

```java
class brandDisplayContent extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
          height: 450,
          width: size.width,
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:200),

          color: Color.fromRGBO(132, 119, 240, 100),

          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            children: [
              brandText(),
              littleTitleText(),
            ],
          )
      ),
    );
  }
}

Text brandText(){
  return Text(
    "BRANDEE",
    style: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.white,
      fontSize: 45,
      letterSpacing: 8,
    ),
    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
  );
}

Text littleTitleText(){
  return Text(
    "Play to rise",
    style: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.white,
      fontSize: 18,
    ),
    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
  );
}
```

Comment: Try to Wrap Column1 with SingleChildScrollView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach is to consider using the Expanded widget inside a Column. That way you don't need to get the Size, and just set size as a proportion using the Flex Property.

An example to roughly show a similar layout...

```
return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          Expanded(
              flex: 3,
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.red,
                child: Column(children: [
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 2,
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 3,
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.yellow,
                    ),
                  ),
                ]),
              )),
          Expanded(
            flex: 2,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  /// Repeat
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
Scaffold(
  body: SizedBox(
    width: size.width,
    height: size.height,
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          flex: 5,
          child: Container(
              width: size.width,
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:size.height*0.2),
              color: const Color.fromRGBO(132, 119, 240, 100),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                children: [
                  brandText(),
                  littleTitleText(),
                ],
              )
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 3,
          child: Container(
              color: Colors.white,
              width: size.width,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    height: 50,
                    width: size.width*0.6,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: const Color.fromRGBO(132, 119, 240, 100),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                    ),
                    child: const Center(
                      child: Text(
                        'Button One',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 20,),
                  Container(
                    height: 50,
                    width: size.width*0.6,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                      border: Border.all(color: const Color.fromRGBO(132, 119, 240, 100)),
                    ),
                    child: const Center(
                      child: Text(
                        'Button Two',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Color.fromRGBO(132, 119, 240, 100)),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Define height as a percentage `height: size.height * .6`

Smartphones have different resolutions, and in such cases do not use a fixed height.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context){
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
          height: size.height * .6,
          width: size.width,
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:200),

          color: Color.fromRGBO(132, 119, 240, 100),

          child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: [
              brandText(),
              littleTitleText(),
          ],
        )
    ),
  );
}
```

and **buttonsDisplayContent** set `height: size.height * .4`

Comment: It's not working, sry :/ I have still the same issue